# django-ses does not send html email

Tags: django, amazon-ses

I am using `django-ses` backend for sending `django-newsletter`. But received emails not contains any html markup.

If i sends with `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`, there is email as i want, and with normal header:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `content_subtype` of your email message object to `text/html`

```
msg = EmailMessage(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])
msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
msg.send()
```

Or you can use [`EmailMultiAlternatives`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types)

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

This way, by default the email html will be rendered, but you will still have a text version to fall back on.